# APNS fails to deliver message after inactivity

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I have created a client-server solution for APNS in PHP.

The "server" is a continously running script that waits for connections and copies the content to APNS. This means it keeps the connection to APNS open all the time. I use fwrite and stream context as such. This is the part that accepts incoming connections:

```
if ($client = @stream_socket_accept($this->socket, -1)) {

   $this->writeLine("Received connection.");

   $this->inputBuffer = stream_get_contents($client);

}
```

It runs in a while-loop, so that next iteration copies the contents of inputBuffer to APNS as such:

```
$writtenBytes = @fwrite($this->connectionAPNS, $this->inputBuffer, strlen($this->inputBuffer));
```

I then check for bytes written like:

```
if ($writtenBytes > 0) {

$this->writeLine("Copied $writtenBytes bytes to APNS.");

   return true;
}
```

Now, the problem arises when the connection has been sitting idle for some time. The first push notification WILL return the number of bytes written to APNS - such as "Copied 157 bytes to APNS.", indicating that the fwrite works, but the message is not delivered.

The next notification then returns 0 bytes written, reconnects automatically (part of my script) and writes the bytes that failed - then it works.

Why do I get bytes written returned if the connection actually failed to write or if APNS did not accept them?

I use the enhanced notification format and I check for errors returned, which seem to be none.

I use this code for that, which I found on a blog, where I pass the connection handle to the function after writing to APNS:

```
function checkAppleErrorResponse($fp)
{
    $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6);

    if ($apple_error_response) {

        error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response);

        if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
            $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';
        } else {
            // Here is some fancy if/else error handling, but I never end in this else , so I excluded it.

        }
     }
}
```

The 'client' part that keeps the connection APNS open looks like this, and is called whenever writtenBytes returns 0 (error) or when the script first loads:

```
function connectToAPNS()
    {

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->certpath);
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $this->passphrase);


        // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $error = "";
        $errno = 0;
        $this->connectionAPNS = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195',
            $errno,
            $error,
            60,
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,
            $ctx
        );

        if ($this->connectionAPNS) {
            stream_set_blocking($this->connectionAPNS, 0);
            $this->writeLine("Connected to APNS!");

            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Same issue here, have you solved it?

Comment: I reconnect after an hour of inactivity. Seems to have worked around it.

Comment: Yes, this should be a good workaround. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a release or a debug version? In each case you have to communicate with a different web-service and use different certificates.

In sandbox/debug mode communicate with *ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195*

In production/relase mode communicate with *ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195*

The notification will be silently dropped, if you communicate with the wrong service.

Comment: It's production. It only fails on the first notification after inactivity - all the later ones will arrive properly.

I'm well aware of the difference between sandbox and production - that's not the reason for this problem :)

Comment: Ok. I couldn't see it in your source and it's a common pitfall. I would improve the return code checks like:
if (fwrite(...) === false) {
  throw new Exception();
}
Btw. can you ensure that your device is online. Apple has a QoS component that only delivers the newest notification when the device is offline: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4

Comment: fwrite returns the number of bytes written. It doesn't return false. If it did I could just rewrite as I normally do. The problem is that it returns the bites written for the first notification, then false on next message - first message is then lost.

Comment: Device is online. I work with only one token and one device for tests.

Comment: Have you tried to set the write buffer to 0? 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-write-buffer.php
 
Perhaps the bytes are buffered while the connection gets lost. Sending to Apple can take a while due to Network latency.

Comment: I'll have a look and try

Comment: No write buffer changes nothing. After 12 hours of inactivity, for instance, I can write to the socket, get a successful write, but no delivery. If I then retry, I get an error ,reconnect and then a successful write and delivery.

Comment: Additionally you could wait 400 ms after write and try to flush the write buffer with fflush afterwards. I've seen it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246163/apns-messages-are-delivered-but-not-received-on-ios-device?rq=1